# finding preg_match_all with a lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the current line

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=, ")<b>[\d\D]+(?="\)\;})/',$str,$matches);
```

where as $str is equal to

`906), "<b>tadam tadam 393943</b>");});`

for some reason it won't find matches, how is that?

**UPDATE** 
In order for it to work I needed to add U at 
the end of the regex, so it wouldn't be greedy... 
go figure.

Comment: it match `<b>tadam tadam 393943</b>`

Answer (score 1):

It does match, you just have to specify the group with parentheses:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=, ")(<b>[\d\D]+)(?="\)\;})/',$str,$matches);
```

So that the fragment matching `<b>[\d\D]+` can be accessed via `$matches[1][0]`.